# Dark mode switch with prefers-color-scheme: dark

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a toggle switch for enabling dark mode.

```
<div class="one-quarter d-flex justify-content-center" id="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="chk" />
    <label class="switch-label" for="chk">
      <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
      <div class="ball"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

With some javascript I am able make a switch for an element

```
const chk = document.getElementById('chk');

chk.addEventListener('change', () => {

});
```

And then put all the dark styling in:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

}
```

How can I make the switch work to enable prefers-color-scheme: dark

Comment: Do you want to change the theme of the page if user's default scheme is dark?

Comment: The default theme is light. When user uses the toggle/switch theme should change to the  prefers-color-scheme: dark. With prefers-color-scheme: dark it already works when the user pc/laptop/mobile is in dark mode.

Comment: I have replied with an answer I think will be more appropriate for your case. Hope it helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way would be to use CSS variables, so you wont' have to load a whole new css file altogether and it's slick

```css
 :root {
    --primary-color: #302AE6;
    --secondary-color: #536390;
    --font-color: #424242;
    --bg-color: #fff;
    --heading-color: #292922;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
    --primary-color: #9A97F3;
    --secondary-color: #818cab;
    --font-color: #e1e1ff;
    --bg-color: #161625;
    --heading-color: #818cab;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--font-color);
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    color: var(--heading-color);
    font-family: "Sansita One", serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
}
```

and with JS you can toggle that

```js
const chk = document.getElementById('chk');

chk.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
 if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    }
    else {        
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');    
    }   
});
```

Comment: Ooh that's neat. So I can leave out `prefers-color-scheme: dark`
Would I still be able then to auto detect if the device/pc is in dark mode?

Comment: You can change the colors using same CSS variables in  `prefers-color-scheme: dark` query. So yeah it will also work in that case.

Comment: I see. I'll fiddle around a bit with this. Looks like a clean solution.

Comment: You can refer to this article for more information https://dev.to/ananyaneogi/create-a-dark-light-mode-switch-with-css-variables-34l8

Comment: Awesome, tried it out and works! Is there also a way to remember being switched to dark mode? Since I've multiple pages but when browsing it changes back to normal

Comment: Yes try storing it in localStorage, i.e. `localStorage.setItem('dark);` and on page load check if it's dark change the page theme to dark as you would on toggle button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214210/discussion-between-zain-zafar-and-mark).

Comment: This solution looks great, except I can't figure out if there's a way to replace the media query in `<picture><source srcset="..." media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)">`. I use dark/light mode images for some logos and icons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can create custom CSS media queries like that.

Depending on you flexibility, you could try a different approach like this :

1. Store all the non-theme-dependent CSS in a file (say, `style.css`)
2. Store the light/dark theme css in their specific files (say, `lighttheme.css` and `darktheme.css`)
3. In your HTML, put a link to your CSS like this :

```
<!-- General CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<!-- Theme-specific CSS (Note the ID attribute!) -->
<link id="theme_css" rel="stylesheet" href="lighttheme.css" />
```

4. Change the `href` attribute of your theme CSS like this :

```
$('#chk').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    // Set dark theme
    $("#theme_css").href = "darktheme.css";
  } else {
    // Set light theme
    $("#theme_css").href = "lighttheme.css";
  }
});
```

---

That's not *exactly* what you asked for, but it could work if you can implement something like this :)

Comment: Yeah I just saw that solution somewhere. Perhaps it would be best to go this way. My default theme is light by itself. So I would just need the darktheme.css I guess? would I then still be able to detect if the device/pc is in dark mode and apply darktheme.css accordingly?

Comment: Yes, if it already works with only a darktheme.css then you don't need a lighttheme.css. Instead of replacing the `href` value, you would deactivate the link to the CSS. (You can try replacing the `href` with blank, for example)