# W3Schools.com Toggle CSS Dark Mode- Local Storage Javascript Question

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage

This is my first time posting - so apologies if this is a simple question!

I'm using the W3Schools.com Toggle Dark Mode which works really well. This switches the theme from dark to light via a toggle button.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_dark_mode.asp

but it doesn't store the settings, so if I leave the page or refresh the browser it reverts back to the default styling.

The current javascript for this page is:

```
    function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

The HTML toggle button code is:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>
```

I'm guessing I need to use some form of local storage via javascript to save the dark-mode choice. This is where I get stuck as I have no idea how to do this. I've searched everywhere on Google but nothing I've tried works.

If possible could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance, kind regards

Brian

Comment: The advert-ridden tutorial mill site you are looking at is called W3Schools. There is no C in the name. It has nothing to do with the W3C.

Comment: The approach that site takes with respect to dark mode is **awful**, it completely ignores the user's system preferences for dark mode. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61899858/dark-mode-switch-with-prefers-color-scheme-dark for a better approach.